# How to explore / collect the audio resources of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, image, audio, collections, document

I installed a chat widget on a webpage which emits notification sounds. I would like to reuse one of the sound effects on the page by playing it by a JavaScript call. How can I collect the audio resources of the page? For example there is `document.images` for images, but what about audio elements? Maybe some of them are instantiated by calling `new Audio()`. Is it possible to collect them all somehow, maybe by traversing the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can review requested media resource at `DevTools` `Network` tab by selecting `Media` menu item. Note, an `AudioNode` can load media and begin playback without being appended to an `html` `document`.